# How do I View the functions inside of DLLs?

Tags: dll, header, reverse-engineering

Is there a way you can open and view the code in a DLL (i.e., see functions/methods, signatures, and the code inside those functions or methods?)

Is there a way to view any headers inside the DLL as well as the authorship information for a DLL?

Comment: @DourHighArch seems like you love flagging, but why so? target question was asked more than 2 years after this question. So flag that one. Flagger :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they are .NET DLLs, you can find out a remarkable amount, including disassembling the code, using redgate's free tool "Reflector" - see http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/

Answer (score 6):

for non-.Net windows DLLs, there is this one here:

http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find what you need (and more) in [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to do it programmatically and write your own tool. Then have a look at the [import and export tables of the COFF format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable).

Some other tools with source code doing it are:
[Texe](http://texe.codeplex.com/) and [LordPE](http://www.woodmann.com/collaborative/tools/index.php/LordPE)

Answer (score 0):

As material for my own lectures for Reverse Engineering, I developed PeStudio (www.winitor.net/en/pestudio.html). Using this tool you can snoop many details about imported and exported functions. You can even undecorate these when these have been decorated by a compiler.