# Where does One Click Office Add ins store ribbon image file

Tags: .net, vsto, oneclick

I've created a ribbon button in .NET using VSTO and published it using One Click, however I'm curious as to where the button image is stored on the computer.  Furthermore, I'm wondering if I can update this image manually (or programmatically) without publishing a new version of the VSTO add-in.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you know that unless your addin is designed for this scenario, what you want to do is far from the intended way to update the image.

You could try this link: [How do I programmatically find the deployed files for a VSTO Add-In?](https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2010/07/11/how-do-i-programmatically-find-the-deployed-files-for-a-vsto-add-in/) but I just tried it for mine and no images are showing up (I do have some, in the project Resources).

But I suspect it's in .\Application Files\<< your_addin_name>>.dll.deploy, wherever you published it to. This is just the normal dll, [with '.deploy' appended](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0b3f2292-d6b8-4666-bcd9-876310d5706b/what-exactly-is-a-deploy-file-can-i-simply-copy-and-paste-a-sdfdeploy-file-to-backup-database?forum=winformssetup). I don't know much about opening DLLs, but [this might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050615/how-to-open-dll-files-to-see-what-is-written-inside).