# How do I edit a c# dll

Tags: c#, dll

I have a c# project that includes a dll which I need to make changes to. So I decompiled it using dotpeek, exported the code and made my changes. Now I need to recompile it to add it back to my project.

The issue is that I am not sure if I am going about this problem the right way. And if I was how would I recompile the code into a dll again?

Sorry about this question but I am new to c# and visual studio but thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you clarify whether you are trying to open your updated project or dll file? its not clear from the question. Having said that both could be opened in visual studio for editing purposes.

Comment: check this post as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050615/how-to-open-dll-files-to-see-what-is-written-inside

Comment: Side note: in most cases getting decompiled code to build requires way more knowledge than "new to C#" (in addition to likely be very questionable from legal point of view, but that is generally not a concern for SO posts as there are plenty valid reasons to do that too). Searching for existing questions on the same topic could give some insight into pains you should expect - https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23%20recompile%20assembly%20dotpeek%20site%3Astackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a new C# project in visual studio, put the decompiled code in the new project and then you can convert the modified decompiled code back to dll which can be referenced in your project.